# ssh2-sftp-client uploading first file just fine, but rest of the files with 0 bytes

Tags: node.js

At node, Im using ssh2-sftp-client and uploading several files which names are in an array.

The first file is uploading perfect, but the rest of the files are uploaded with 0 byte.

Here is my code:

```
let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
let sftp = new Client();

await sftp.connect({
    host: 'ftp.somedomain.net',
    port: '22',
    username: 'myftpusername',
    password: 'myftppassword',
    "algorithms": {
        "kex": [
            "diffie-hellman-group14-sha1", "diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1"
        ]
    }
}).then(() => {
    for (let file of ftpFiles) {
        sftp.fastPut(file.local, file.remote)
    }

}).then(data => {

}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
});
sftp.close;
```

Also, Im not getting any error at the console.

If I upload only one file, it works fine. The problem is with multiple files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm a little late, but you need to use async/await.

```
then(async () => {
  for (const file of ftpFiles) {
    try {
      await sftp.fastPut(file, "path/to/some/directory/on/ftp/"+file)
    }catch(error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}).then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
}).finally(() => {
  console.log("closing FTP connection");
  sftp.end();
});
```